# Set and remove menu background-color using jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I make the background-color of the home link in this jsfiddle default blue, but when another link is clicked it is no longer blue?

I tried using `windows.onload` but the blue background remained.

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>           
        <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $targetElement = $("#menu a");
    $targetElement.click(function() {
       $targetElement.removeClass("currentlink");
       $(this).addClass("currentlink");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KR4ed/

Answer (score 2):

Set the class from the start in the html like this

```
<li><a href="#" class="currentlink">Home</a></li>
```

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KR4ed/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var setId = $.cookie("currentId");
    if (typeof setId !== "undefined") {
        $("#menu a").removeClass("currentlink");
        $('#' + setId).addClass("currentlink"); // currentlink set using cookie
    }
    var $targetElement = $("#menu a");
    $targetElement.click(function () {
        $targetElement.removeClass("currentlink");
        $(this).addClass("currentlink");
        var lastID = $(this).attr("id");
        $.cookie('currentId', lastID);
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cBMFW/)

**Note:** you have to add **jquery.cookie.min.js** then just add the above code. see the jsfiddle demo for reference.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was after, but when I reload the page, if I'm viewing link2, the home link goes back to the blue background, and link2 has no background. Is there a way to stop this happening? This is a one page website, and clicking on the link scrolls to that section.

Comment: @tatty ya sure please check my updated answer and jsfiddle demo link

Comment: I copied the code exactly and the home permanently has the background, and clicking on the other links does nothing now. The jsfiddle works so I don't know where I went wrong.

Comment: @tatty what is the error you getting when you run the above code?

Comment: The home link permanently has the blue background, and the other links have none when clicked on.

Comment: @tatty please see the jsfiddle demo and make sure that your code is same as jsfiddle demo.